# How to stock value from tkinter in an efficient way?

Tags: python, tkinter, get

I have some problems with tkinter. I want to ask for some values and stock those values. I found some code about get() method but here are my questions:
Here is code:

`
from tkinter import*

```
window= Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

#1)
def getEntry():
    result= a.get()
    print(result)

a = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10, command=getEntry)       
a.pack()

#2)
def getEntry2():
    result=s.get()
    return result

s = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10, command=getEntry2)  
print(s)
s.pack()
#3)
def getEntry3():
    result=Trees.get()
    print(result)
Trees= Listbox(window, command=getEntry3)
Trees.insert(1, "Tree1")
Trees.insert(2, "Tree2")
Trees.pack()
```

bouton_close= Button(window, text="Fermer", command=window.quit)
bouton_close.pack()

window.mainloop()

`

1. I dont understand why I have to create a function each time I want a result. It doesn't look efficient to have many function doing the same thing just with different names. like if my all code was using only function like getEntry() function? WAnd how could compact the code? hy is it not possible to do something like that? :

`def getEntry(name): result=name.get() print(result) a = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10, command=getEntry(a))`

2. Is it possible to stock the value ? because I can print the value (getEntry) but when I try to return the value, there is no error but it doesn't print anything (getEntry2)
3. Why with Listbox (getEntry3) "command" is not reconnized ? "unknown optin "-command"

Tanks you for your help !!

Comment: Tutorial and stackoverflow you for your help! 1. How to pass variables to a callback function. 2. Binding Widgets to Variables. 3 Listbox - Listbox in tutorial.

Comment: The formatting of the code needs some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

1-There is a way to call same function for multiple widgets. That is by using lambda you pass widget itself to function.

2-As you call it from button call, there is no where to return the value. you can use global variables which is not adviced, or you can use classes.

3-Listboxes like treeviews, has some major differences from other widgets. So if you wanna use it like that you should bind events.

```
from tkinter import *

window= Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

def getEntry(entry):
    result= entry.get()
    print(result)

def getTree(et):
    tree = et.widget
    index = int(tree.curselection()[0])
    value = tree.get(index)
    print(value)

a = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10)       
a.configure(command=lambda:getEntry(a))
a.pack()

b = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10)       
b.configure(command=lambda:getEntry(b))
b.pack()

c = Spinbox(window, from_=0, to=10)       
c.configure(command=lambda:getEntry(c))
c.pack()


Trees= Listbox(window)
Trees.insert(1, "Tree1")
Trees.insert(2, "Tree2")
Trees.pack()
Trees.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',getTree)


bouton_close= Button(window, text="Fermer", command=window.quit) 
bouton_close.pack()

window.mainloop()
```